# Magento 2 How to create back order programmatically

Tags: magento2, programmatically, backorder

I have created order programatically for my some of the store products and it's created
successfully. but my some products are 0 qty than also i want to create order for that 0 qty products.

can someone please suggest how i can do that.

**Note : i do not want to enable backorder from system configuration , i want whole things programatically.**

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the quantity and stock status validation while order pragmatically by using below code :

```
$product->setIsSuperMode(true);
$product->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);
$product->setData('is_salable', true);
$quote->setIsSuperMode(true);
$quote->setIgnoreOldQty(true);
```

NOTE : All these object need to be set before adding product to quote. Also, it will only work if your not using MSI, if you are using MSI then some more plugin need to be implement to skip those check.

Comment: which event is needed for this code?

Answer (score 0):

"0 qty", means this product is out of stock? If I'm not misinterpreting what you mean, you're trying to place an order with products that are out of stock.
This is absolutely impossible.

When you place an order Magento will automatically check the products you are ordering. If it's out of stock, the order will fail and you won't be able to continue to the next steps